# menupopup with vbox closed after hover (Firefox extension)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

```
            <menu id="list-menu" class="icon-list menu-iconic" label="Menu list">
                <menupopup>
                    <vbox flex="1" class="help">
                        <html:div class="help-text">
                            <label>Here is help text</label>
                        </html:div> 
                    </vbox>
                    <vbox flex="1" class="list" id="list-box">
                        Here is box with default height 300px;
                    </vbox>
                    <vbox flex="1">
                        <button class="button" value="Here is button" />
                        <button class="button" value="Here is button 2" />                          
                    </vbox>
                </menupopup>
            </menu>
```

If I sharply bring the mouse cursor to elements in menupopup it closes. How to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand man. Can you take a screencast and share? How do you sharply move a mouse? Quickly? Do you mean quickly hover over it? I can't resimulate that where a quick hover over and through and off of the element makes it hide. But why are you putting `vbox`'s in a `menupopup`, you should use a `panel` if you want to do that. IF you want a menu xul element than you should have `menuitem`'s in place of those `vbox'`s and no need for the `html:div` or `label` elements. On the `menuitem` you should put label. Can you share your main code, I'll take a look at it and hook up a panel for u.

Comment: @Noitidart, sorry for my bad English. I record a video for you. (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tbq83w5fZ98)

Comment: No need for apology please man. I appreciate the video I'll check it out now. :) Ok I saw the video. Do you have your source code on github? Ill take a look and help you out. You should definitely use a panel for this, not a menu.

Comment: @Noitidart, yes, here is my repo: https://github.com/Exclumice/firex. I just need replace menu tag to panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I see now, it wasn't seen in the video but this is a submenu that opens when your mouse is over the menuitem.

[image: LINK TO IMAGE].

So when you hover your mouse over the "Proxy List >" `menuitem`, which opens the sub-`menuitem`, and now want to move your mouse from this `menuitem` over the submenu that opened, you MUST move your mouse carefully keeping it hovered over the "Proxy List >" `menuitem`. If your mouse goes off of the this "Proxy List >" `menuitem` before it reaches the sub-`menuitem` than it will make your sub-`menuitem` disapper EVEN IF your mouse is now over the sub-`menuitem`. To work around this you have to prevent the popup from hiding IF the mouse is over your sub-`menuitem`. I'll write a thing for you here I'll go work on it. My solution will do a `stopPropogation` on `popuphiding` if the users mouse is over this panel. **But posting this here so @nmaier can see what your issue is, maybe he has better ideas while I'm working.**

---

Ok here's the solution:
In `overlay.xul` added the `onmousenter` `onmouseleave`, and `onmousedown` attributes like this:

```
<menupopup onmouseenter="Components.utils.reportError('entered');this.addEventListener('popuphiding', ProxyAddonBar.preventHide, false)" onmousedown="Components.utils.reportError('downed');this.removeEventListener('popuphiding', ProxyAddonBar.preventHide, false)" onmouseleave="Components.utils.reportError('left');this.removeEventListener('popuphiding', ProxyAddonBar.preventHide, false)">
```

Then in `overlay.js` and this function:

```
preventHide: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Components.utils.reportError('PREVENTED HIDE'); //you can remove this, this is just a debug message to tell you when it hides
}
```

So now this does what you want, you can try by installing the addon from my fork: https://github.com/Noitidart/firex/

Edit:
Ok I figured out your second problem where it was hiding even after we implemented the above. What happend was now the opposite. If you carefully moved from "Proxy List >" to the submenu, and now from here you quickly moved from submenu to to "Proxy List >" but on the way you moused over "Disable Proxy", it will hide it, this is normal expected behavior, but if you want to prevent that, I understand. Forget that `stopPropogation` thing I'll edit the code above. So solution to this is to add to the `<menu>` tag these attributes: `onmouseenter="this.childNodes[0].addEventListener('popuphiding', ProxyAddonBar.preventHide, false)" onmouseleave="this.childNodes[0].removeEventListener('popuphiding', ProxyAddonBar.preventHide, false)"`

It was also triggering false enter and left events, while moving mouse within the sub-menuitem. So I fixed that by checking for `event.relatedTarget`.

So combining both solutions above, in overlay.xul we have this now:

```
    <menu id="proxy-list-menu" class="icon-list menu-iconic" label="&proxy-list;" onmouseenter="this.childNodes[0].addEventListener('popuphiding', ProxyAddonBar.preventHide, false)" onmouseleave="this.childNodes[0].removeEventListener('popuphiding', ProxyAddonBar.preventHide, false)">
<menupopup onmouseenter="if (!event.relatedTarget) { Components.utils.reportError('entered');this.addEventListener('popuphiding', ProxyAddonBar.preventHide, false) }" onmousedown="Components.utils.reportError('downed');this.removeEventListener('popuphiding', ProxyAddonBar.preventHide, false)" onmouseleave="if (!event.relatedTarget) { Components.utils.reportError('left');this.removeEventListener('popuphiding', ProxyAddonBar.preventHide, false) }">
```

---

*Question for @nmaier. After making my change, if you move the mouse from the "Proxy List >" submenu item and accidentally hover off, but end up with your cursor on the sub-`menuitem` it prevents the hide. If you then move your mouse off and onto "Disalbe Proxy" `menuitem` or "Check connection speed" it will NOT hide the sub-menuitem even though I already removed the `preventHide` function. It will only close if you hover over "Proxy List >" again.*

*IF you open the submenu by hovering over "Proxy List >" and carefully take your mouse to the submenu that opened without accidentally leaving the "Proxy List >" item, then once you reach the submenuitem then leave it by hovering on to "Disable Proxy" or "Check connection speed", it will close after like a second. So this is the normal hide behavior, how come when I preven the hide, it doesnt hide like normal once I hover over these other labels?*

Comment: Try what man? I didn't post the solution yet! :P Give me 10 more min

Comment: I tried do it for test:

  document.getElementById('proxy-list-menu').addEventListener("popuphiding", function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   Firebug.Console.log(e.target);
  }, false);

but did not work :#

Comment: Ok man I edited in the solution. But it has a sub question for a small qwirk for @nmaier. It's not that big a deal but i like things perfect.

Comment: Oh shoot you're right. Ok change the `onmouseleave` attribute to this `if (!event.relatedTarget) { Components.utils.reportError('left');this.removeEventListener('popuphiding',ProxyAddonBar.preventHide,false); }`

Comment: Ok I figured out your problem. What happend was now the opposite. If you carefully moved from "Proxy List >" to the submenu, and now from here you quickly moved from submenu to to "Proxy List >" but on the way you moused over "Disable Proxy", it will hide it, this is normal expected behavior, but if you want to prevent that, I understand. Forget that `stopPropogation` thing I'll edit the code above.

Comment: Ok edited it in above check it out. Make sure to remove that `stopPropagation`

Comment: PS: after my second solution, you will need to add to the "Activate" and "Refresh List" buttons within the submenu like: `onmousedown="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeEventListener('popuphiding', ProxyAddonBar.preventHide, false);"` otherwise when you click in the panel it wont hide the panel.

Comment: Welcome :) Well it's not totally perfect yet, see the outstanding question for @nmaier I hope he can give his advice on that :(, I tried `enableRollup` and it wouldn't revert that small qwirk.